# Simple asp.net webforms productivity tool

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access, datagrid, webforms

Let me say in advance: I use Visual Studio, am not a full-time programmer, use webforms to create simple database driven applictions. I find the default controls in VS sill quite devious to use in making frontend applications compared to similar controls in a product like MsAccess.

I'm looking for functionality like simple masterdetail-linking and using datagrids with simple datadriven comboboxes (again functionality MsAccess has out of the box for over more than 10 years).

I know there are productivity-suites like DevCraft en DevExpress, but in the past I often found these too big for the purpose I have (plus they are quite expensive when you have to pay form them yourself).

Advice would be more than welcome after again a day of frustrating programming.

Answer (score 1):

Ad, you might gave a look at [Microsoft LightSwitch](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=quL3v3pnLWY)

I also build applications in Access before I started to use Webforms and I also thought that it was too complicated to build master/detail forms like an invoice header, with invoice-rows, but I don't think you will find any solutions in Webforms.

What's more: webforms itself, is a very simple way to build web-apps and I already went 'further' to MVC. When you start developing in MVC you also start looking for web-form style controls like GridView but they aren't there anymore. The more you learn about web-development, the more you understand that it will take a long time before those apps can be me in the same way as Access-applications.

That said: I think LightSwitch is positioned as the web-equivalent of MsAccess.

Comment: As I said: I'm short of time to seriously dive into all possible .net related techniques, but from what I read LightSwitch looks like an interesting option. Thanks!